# Вывести каждое слово исключая пунктуацию из файла с новой строки в терминал

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, text

Я хочу каждое слово в тексте вывести отдельно на новой строке. Например, у меня есть файл `about-me.txt`, в котором записан такой текст:

```
Hello! My name is Belle Pepper. I love ice cream.
Do you love? I am 26
```

Желаемый результат:

```
Hello
My
name
is
Belle
Pepper
I 
love
... # и т.д. до конца файла
```

Я написала такой код, но он не работает:

```
cat about-me.txt| tr '' '\n'>separeted.txt`.
```

Comment: only russian please, you have to translate your question to russian.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor я переводит на русский. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: А что с остатком в файле после "Pepper"? От первой точки надо всё   обрезать?

Comment: @0xdb нет. Просто я не дописала до конца

Comment: Что тогда с точкой, а  также с "?"? В желаемом выводе пунктуационные символы отсутствуют.

Comment: @0xdb вот меня цель и заключается в этом. Я не могу избавиться от них

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
$  sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/\n/g;s/[[:punct:]]\+//g' about-me.txt
```

Или так:

```
$  perl -pe 's/\s+/\n/g; s/\pP+//g' about-me.txt
```

Вывод всегда один и тот же:

```
Hello
My
name
is
Belle
Pepper
I
love
... # и т.д., всего 16 строк
```

Comment: Какая версия *sed* умеет *\s*?

Comment: @0andriy sed (GNU sed) 4.4

Comment: Ответ неверный. Та, которая собрана с `pcre`. Поэтому ответ лучше уточнить.

Comment: @0andriy Почему неверный? Нельзя использовать sed с pcre?

Comment: Неверный в смысле версии `sed`. А по сути это непереносимо, надо использовать `[[:space:]]`

Comment: @0andriy Куда непереносимо?  Вы не ответили на вопрос - почему нельзя использовать sed собраную с pcre?

Comment: @0xdb, может действительно добавить как опцию версию, не зависящую от PCRE: `sed -e 's/[[:punct:]]\+//g' -e 's/[[:space:]]\+/\n/g' about-me.txt` ?

Comment: @MaxU Ну раз уже два замечания, то неприменно добавлю ))

Comment: @0xdb, это не замечание - это предложение ;)

Comment: @0andriy Вот так теперь правильно? Буду рад узнать ваше мнение!